# combining for loops and if statements with dictionaries in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am working on an exercise in which I'm supposed to have both a list and dictionary and to print out a specified message if the value in the list is not in the dictionary can someone please help? For some reason, it only prints out the else statement, but not the if. I am sure I'm missing something

```
poll_takers = ['angel', 'jana', 'murad', 'adel', 'joe', 'jake']

favorite_language = {
    'angel': 'python',
    'jana': 'c++',
    'murad': 'python',
    'adel': 'swift',
}

for name in poll_takers:
    if name == favorite_language:
        print(name.title() + ", thank you for taking the poll.")
    else:
        print(name.title() + ", please take the poll.")
```

Comment: What do you think `name == favorite_language` means?

Comment: As indicated by the comment by mkrieger - you need to think about why it is only hitting the else - why does name != favourite_language? If it helps you can print out each of these variables to do some quick debugging of your own!

Comment: The `==` tests for *equality*. Look at what is on the left side and what is on the right side. What are the *types* of each of those. Print each out, and see what it is exactly comparing.

Comment: I see what I did wrong now, I thought == would make sure that the string in name would be the same as the key in poll_takers, and I didn't know I can use "in" within an if statement my bad. and thank you all for the help

Comment: I don't know why I am getting negative votes I don't understand what's wrong with my question? this is my first post, and now I can't ask again because of the negative votes...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your conditional should be

```
if name in favorite_language
```

which checks if a key is in the dictionary, otherwise

```
if name == favorite_language
```

always evaluates to false since the string name isnt equal to the dictionary, since `==` tests for equality, that's why the else statement keeps getting triggered

Comment: If you are going to answer it, answer it properly. Explain what they are doing wrong.